# can i change keyboard shortcut for move/rotate/size in EDIT mode?

Tags: customization, shortcut

I'm a 3ds max user wanting to switch to blender. To help me with the transition i want to change some keyboard shortcuts. More specificaly the shortcut for move/rotate/size. Don't want to change all of them but some.

In Object mode this is not a problem. I could change it to the 3ds max defaults (W / E / R)
But in EDIT mode i can't seem to change the default (spacebar G / spacebar R / Spacebar S) to the (W / E / R) keyboard shortcut. Is it possible to do this or do i always need to press spacebar first?

Comment: I advice you to learn blender keymap. All tutorials are easier that way. Basic navigation in blender is reasonable, if you change a lot of it, it can affect others. You have to just get use to it, in a week you will dont mind. I started with max, then maya, solidworks, meshmixer at last blender. Wanted to change to max setting as well but after a while I got used to it and it is ok.

Comment: Although your answer makes much sense, at the moment i'm still working on a few 3ds max projects while learning Blender en trying to do as much testing and practicing as possible. So i'm working with both 3d programs on the same day, not being able to have the same keyboard shortcuts is really messing with my mind and workflow. For some reason i couldn't get my keyboards shortcuts to bind in EDIT mode, but today there was no problem after a new try.